# React: how to make one element react on change with the change of its child element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my return of this file, I want to let the header element in  "subtitle " change to same element as the elements in  drop down menu whenever onChange in it is triggered. How shall I modify this code?

```
return (
    <Card
      classname="WeeklyTrafficCard"
      icon={<span><i className="icon-user"/></span>}
      title={<h3>Weekly Traffic Analytics</h3>}
      subtitle={<h5 className="font-light text-muted">Modify This Part, I want it to be each_daterange whenever each_daterange changes</h5>}
    >
      <div className="weekly">
        <div className="weekly-head p-4 text-center">
          <select className="py-2 px-3" onChange={(event)=>setMyVar(event.target.value)}>
            {dateArray.map(each_daterange => (
                <option key={each_daterange} value={each_daterange} >
                  {each_daterange}
                </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="viz px-16">
          {data && data.length > 0 && (
            <canvas width="400" height="400" id="weekly-traffic-chart"></canvas>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Card>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're already using the useState hook. (setMyVar)
You can put myVar in the subtitle, and the component will re-render when myVar changes.

```
<Card
  ...
  subtitle={<h5 className="font-light text-muted">{myVar}</h5>}
>
   {...}
</Card>
```

Comment: Hi, I actually cannot do this because I used useState in the parent file and pass the setState as the prop into this child file. This means myVar is in the parent file and I cannot access myVar from this file.

Comment: How about passing the myVar to this component as props from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript [es6 template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
subtitle={`<h5 className="font-light text-muted">${myVar}</h5>`}
```